# Get current URL + "EN" inside custom button LARAVEL BLADE

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing, laravel-blade

I have an "EN" button and "FR" button. For switching languages.
I tried to put it like this so far:

1.

```
<a href='{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}
```

*But I get an error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [] not defined.*

2.

```
I tried this `<li><a href='{{ Request::url() }}' id="first" class="Mytitle">EN</a></li>`
```

*This only get you current url*

3. This also do not work:
   `{{ url(app()->getLocale() . Request::url() ) }}`

*When you press nothing happened*

What is the proper way to handle URL?

I would like to have current URL with locale language e.g. 
from 
**www.mydomain.com**/en/**services** 

to

**www.mydomain.com**/fr/**services**

Get in mind that I have in routes.php `'prefix'=>'{locale}'`

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out.

In your web.php file, I presume that you have already set the name to the route.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'YourController@yourMethod')->name('your-route-name');
});
```

Now, in your blade view, it should be like this..

```
<a href="{{ route('your-route-name', 'en') }}">EN</a>
```

You have written it in a different way. You can get more information on how to use `route` method in blade views. [Documentation of route method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route)

**Update 1:**

> how to add other part of the url?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}/SERVICES'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'YourController@yourMethod')->name('your-route-name');
});
```

Regarding page translation, I don't know what your application is doing. So, I am at least possible help.

Yes, you're right to a certain extent by using `url(/en)`. But then, you will have to update all the view files. With `route()`, you will have to update only the web.php file once. You need not update the view file, because, you're using the method `route` and Laravel is smart enough to replace the link with appropriate parameters.

For more information, I urge you to go through the [routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing). That will give you more insight about how the `route` is different from `url`

Comment: But how to add other part of the url? en/SERVICES?

Comment: This solution is the same as: {{url('/en')}}

Comment: @RogaMen check the Update 1

Comment: this button is in navbar ... so it needed to be variable to all links. Now only changes the "home" page when I click to the EN button. If I am on other pages for example /services and try to click from FR to EN it redirects me too "home" page.

Answer (score -1):

If the language is static, you could just do:

```html
<li><a href="/en/{{ Request::path() }}" id="first" class="Mytitle">EN</a></li>
```

Comment: Good suggestion but the problem with Request::url() is that it only add URL to current URL, like this:. mydomain.com/fr/serviceshmydomain.com/en/services    So I think that Request::url() is not solution here.

Comment: you are right, my bad, `Route::path()` is what you want there, I updated my answer

Comment: A little bit better but still adding path to the url. Not a good solution.

Comment: Have you added the leading `/` at the start of the href or have a baseUrl set?

Comment: You must click 4 times and see what happen